# Read a state as a String instead of blatantly converting it to any Typescript Antd?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, antd

When I am trying to convert the Javascript Header provided by antd to Typescript, at `<Menu mode={this.state.menuMode} ...` , I get the following error :

> No overload matches this call.
>     Overload 1 of 2, '(props: Readonly): Menu', gave the following error.
>       Type 'String' is not assignable to type '"horizontal" | "inline" | "vertical" | "vertical-left" | "vertical-right" | undefined'.
>
> Type 'String' is not assignable to type '"vertical-right"'.ts(2769)
>   index.d.ts(25, 5): The expected type comes from property 'mode' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes & Readonly & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }>'

This is fixed when I change the dataType of my menuMode in the IState interface to any. However, I figured that there might be a better way to declare this as menuMode is supposed to be a string variable as cross-checked in JSX.

**Is there a fix for this to allow `{this.state.menuMode}` to be read as a string ?**

```
import { Row, Col,  Menu, Button, Popover } from "antd";

interface IProps {}

interface IState {
    menuVisible: Boolean,
    menuMode: String;
}


class Header extends React.PureComponent<IProps, IState> {
  state: IState;

  constructor(props: IProps) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      menuVisible: false,
      menuMode: "horizontal",
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    enquireScreen((b : Boolean) => {
        this.setState({
            menuMode: b ? "inline" : "horizontal"
        });
    });
    }

    render() {

        const menu = (
            <Menu mode={this.state.menuMode} id="nav" key="nav">
            </Menu>
        )

        return (
            <div></div>
        );
    }

}
```

Comment: 1. Don't use `String` and `Boolean` as types, but `string` and `boolean`. 2. It is clear fro the error that the type for `menuMode` should be `"horizontal" | "inline" | "vertical" | "vertical-left" | "vertical-right" | undefined` (not a `String`), pretty sure you can also get its alias from the library you use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://ant.design/components/menu/#Menu

bcuz prop mode have type is `vertical | horizontal | inline`.
Replace type of `menuMode` in `IState` from `String` to a define type like:

```
type MenuMode = 'vertical' | 'vertical-left' | 'vertical-right' | 'horizontal' | 'inline';

interface IState {
    menuVisible: Boolean,
    menuMode: MenuMode;
}
```